# How to Display DropDown component inside a Material UI datagrid with nested data?

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I am using `DataGrid from "@mui/x-data-grid"` 
I want to display and the edit a field 'Region' as a DropDown (Select) with (Value: id, and Text: regionName) which is a nested JSON object.
The user will select from the dropdown menu.
The original JSON obj. is:
{
"id": 2,
"cityName": "Valengo",
"zip": 30179,
"region": {
"id": 1,
"regionName": "New-Yourk"
}
}

here is my field definition:

```
const columns = [..... ,...

field: "region",
      headerName: "RegionName",
      type: "singleSelect",
      editable: true,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        <DropDownRegion>{params.row.region.regionName}</DropDownRegion>;
      }
      
    },
```

**The Region DropDown looks like:**

id , regionName

1, 'New-Yourk'

2, 'San-Fransisco'

I tried the following code to display the regionName, it works, but I can't see DropDown, and I can't edit the regionName.

```
field: "region",
      headerName: "RegionName",
      type: "singleSelect",
      editable: true,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (<DropDownRegion
            regionID={
              typeof params.row.region.id !== "undefined"
                ? params.row.region.id
                : 0
            }
          >
            {params.row.region.regionName}
          </DropDownRegion>);
      }
      
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of the issue is that you are passing the DropDownRegion component to the renderCell prop. When the cell enters in edit mode a different component is rendered. The rest will depend on how the DataGrid is set up.

I had a similar issue recently, in my case I passed a custom component to the renderCell prop, but I didn't set the column as editable to prevent the DataGrid from rendering the renderEditCell component. When you click the cell it will trigger the onClick event on your custom component.

```js
// Column Definition
{
  field: "myField",
  headerName: "My Field",
  renderCell: (params) => (
    <CustomAutoComplete {...params} options={options|| []} onChange={onChange} />
  ),
}
```

It is important to pass an onChange function to your custom component so you can update the rows of the DataGrid.

You can also pass the DropDownRegion to the editRenderCell prop, you might need to do something like this.

```js
// Column Definition
{
  ...GRID_SINGLE_SELECT_COL_DEF, // not to sure if you'll need this
  field: "region",
  headerName: "RegionName",
  type: "singleSelect",
  editable: true,
  renderCell: (params) => {
    <DropDownRegion {...params}>{params.row.region.regionName}</DropDownRegion>;
  }
}
```

And then on your custom component

```js
import { useGridApiContext } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
function DropDownRegion({id,field,value, ...props}){
  const apiRef = useGridApiContext();

  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    apiRef.current.setEditCellValue({ id, field, value: newValue });
  };

  return(<YOUR_JSX>)
}
```

In this approach, you don't need to mutate the rows that are passed to the DataGrid.

I haven't tried this approach yet, but you can have a better look at this example from MUI's documentation: [Custom Date Picker Demo](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=Demo.tsx)

Note: There's another thing I'm unclear about your example: how do you pass the list of options to the DropDown component? Is it hardcoded, or does the component itself have some logic to retrieve them?